# i integrate ant design but it cannot give me a complete component

Tags: reactjs

hi guys i intergrate ant design component in my project but when i run my application it cannot give me complete component

what is that issue ?? i missed any file ??

here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import Home from './components/home';



 import { Layout, Menu, Icon } from 'antd';
  const { Header, Sider, Content } = Layout;

  class App extends Component {
  constructor()
  {
   super()
   this.state = {
    collapsed: false,
    }
   // this.coming=this.coming.bind(this);

    }
   toggleCollapsed = () => {
     this.setState({
    collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
   });
   }
```

here is my render function

```
render() {
return (
  <Layout>
  <Sider
    trigger={null}
    collapsible
    collapsed={this.state.collapsed}
  >
    <div className="logo" />
    <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}>
      <Menu.Item key="1">
        <Icon type="user" />
        <span>nav 1</span>
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="2">
        <Icon type="video-camera" />
        <span>nav 2</span>
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="3">
        <Icon type="upload" />
        <span>nav 3</span>
      </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  </Sider>
  <Layout>
    <Header style={{ background: '#fff', padding: 0 }}>
      <Icon
        className="trigger"
        type={this.state.collapsed ? 'menu-unfold' : 'menu-fold'}
        onClick={this.toggle}
      />
    </Header>
    <Content style={{ margin: '24px 16px', padding: 24, background: '#fff', minHeight: 280 }}>
      Content
    </Content>
  </Layout>
</Layout>
);
```

here is component code which i want to intergrate but it cannot display properly ...almost no styling were apply on that but i also add this css in my code

Comment: Please provide some code so we could help you out.

Comment: now check this please

Comment: Did you include `import 'antd/lib/style/index.css'` in your code ?